# looping error with dns lookup

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I tried to resolve two host names to one IP Address using bind

I was trying to resolve plasam.xyz and eztapz.com to 195.181.214.49
so that I may run both hostnames from one ip address. My own dig on plasam.xyz
gave a SERVFAIL whereas the eztapz.com hostname resolves fine.

The config for eztapz.com and plasam.xyz are:

- https://hastebin.com/lupokopete
- https://hastebin.com/ifikuqaber

I'm sorry I'm really new to bind and its probably a stupid error.

I used

mxtoolbox . com

and it told me they were looping,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `plasam.xyz` zone configured in your `named.conf`, too? What's in your logs after `rndc reload`?

Comment: I dont appear to have any error logs for bind what logs would I be checking?  I found this in the query log: 17-Jun-2017 16:20:26.117 client <my ip>#51615 (plasam.xyz): query: plasam.xyz IN A + (195.181.221.231) I posted early but yes it is in my named.conf.local [here](https://hastebin.com/riwuzenitu.scala)

Comment: @EsaJokinen Thanks for your help but it is now resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The parent servers report that ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com are the name servers for plasam.xyz but neither ns1.eztapz.com nor ns2.eztapz.com respond to DNS queries. Fix that and you'll fix your problem.

Additionally, ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com resolve to the same ip address. You must have a minimum of two name servers that DO NOT resolve to the same ip address.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/vivasilupu.nginx my cmd reports both say they responded fine. what's wrong with two servers that resolve to the same ip if  its for small loads? It seems to work at the moment

Comment: `1.` Your query was a query for the name servers for plasam.xyz, but you didn't query the name servers for plasam.xyz themselves. I can query Google's public DNS servers for the name servers for plasam.xyz but that only tells me which name servers are the name servers for plasam.xyz, it doesn't query the name servers for plasam.xyz themselves. `2.` You need at least two independent name servers because the relevant DNS RFC's say that you need them.

Comment: Why does my server respond to queries for eztapz.com but not plasam.xyz? and why when I set my DNS as 195.181.221.231 (my server) does it start responding to dns queries for plasam.xyz? I shall look at the DNS RDC's now thanks

Comment: The name servers listed for plasam.xyz are ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com (which are actually the same server). Does ns1.eztapz.com/ns2.eztapz.com have a DNS zone for plasam.xyz that it is authoritative for? Additionally, the name server(s) doesn't appear to be reachable from the public internet.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that i'm new thanks for the support I have my named.conf.local set like so https://hastebin.com/icuyavonab.scala and plasam.xyz.db set like so https://hastebin.com/ifikuqaber

Comment: Right. Your plasam.xyz zone file lists ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com as the name servers for plasam.xyz. So does ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com have a zone file for plasam.xyz? Additionally, are ns1.eztapz.com and ns2.eztapz.com reachable from the internet? It appears that they aren't.

Comment: I changed my eztapz.com.db to this to give an A Record to ns1 and ns2 how would I add the zone file? I thought using named.conf.local did that. eztapz.com.db:  https://hastebin.com/fosemuvino.vbs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60645/discussion-between-joss-bird-and-joeqwerty).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know how but the error resolved itself. I must have made a syntax error and when re-typing it all must not have made the same mistake.

Comment: using `named-checkzone` and `named-checkconf` will help wtih that :)

Answer (score -1):

you cannot use multiple "A" records for the same IP (or you can do it but with same names, for failover)

create one "A" record to the IP (eztapz for example)
and then create a "CNAME" record to the A record (plasam pointing to eztapz)

and both will resolve to the same IP

Comment: I did this and removed plasam.xyz.db and changed to eztapz.com.db to [this](https://hastebin.com/okavuwutig.vbs) and still the same error after i restarted bind.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Any idea how to fix my issue please?

Comment: **This is not true.** There could be as many `A` records pointing to a single IP as you wish. Consider wildcard `*.example.com. A` that's already an infinite number of `A` records pointing to a single IP. There should be only one _pointer_ `PTR` record per IP in _reverse_ DNS presenting the canonical hostname, but that's totally different. Also, using `CNAME` on the base domain `example.com` is not recommended as it prevents using any other records including `MX`, `TXT` and `NS`. Therefore this answer is leading to a wrong direction.